# Visual Studio doesn't recognize @model directive

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble getting Visual Studio to recognize the @model directive in MVC3. As a result, I'm not getting any Intellisense help. For example, I just loaded up the standard base MVC3 project in Visual Studio and it shows all sorts of errors in LogOn.cshtml since it can't figure out what the view model is. However, if I run the application everything works just fine. So I guess this is more of an annoyance than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update make sure you have set the `webpages` Version in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    ...
</appSettings>
```

Then simply close and reopen the view and syntax highlighting and Intellisense should come back.

---

UPDATE:

Reinstalling ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update solves the problem.

Comment: I have that in the main Web.config. However, there is another Web.config under the Views folder where the value of it is set to "false".

Comment: No need to modify that one. It's the main web.config. Is this for all ASP.NET MVC 3 projects or a particular one? What happens if you create a new project from scratch?

Comment: This is the out of the box MVC3 project.

Comment: OK, guess reinstalling ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update might be necessary. If this doesn't help the next step is VS2010. I've heard people having similar problems and reinstalling fixed it. Maybe you have installed some betas or plugins that might have jeopardized Razor Intellisense.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like reinstalling MVC 3 tools did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Kyle, glad I could help. I have updated my answer to include this information.